# Custom UISlider ios - Touch is not working

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uigesturerecognizer, nstimer, uislider

i have made Custom Slider using PanGesture for my audio Player using AVAudioPlayer.In which i have used NSTimer to track current time of my Audio, In that case sometime touch is not working to move Slider. It became not Un-Draggable. After that if i tries on or more time to move then it works nicely also.

Edit :

```
-(void)setData{
    minPoint=totalSeekBar.frame.origin;
    maxPoint=CGPointMake(totalSeekBar.frame.size.width+minPoint.x, minPoint.y);
    knob.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(knobPanned:)];
    [knob addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
    [self setSliderForPosition:_currentPosition WithAnimation:YES];


}

-(void)setSliderForPosition:(CGFloat)position WithAnimation:(BOOL)shouldAnimate{
    CGFloat totalWidth=totalSeekBar.frame.size.width+totalSeekBar.frame.origin.x;

    if(position<_maxValue){
        CGFloat newX=(position*totalWidth)/_maxValue;
        [self setKnobToPoint:CGPointMake(newX,0) animated:shouldAnimate delegateCall:NO];

    }


}

-(void)knobPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    [_delegate sliderIsMoving];
    _isUpdating=YES;
    [self setKnobToPoint:[sender locationInView:self] animated:NO delegateCall:YES];

    if(sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        _currentPosition=[self getNewCurrentValueForPoint:[sender locationInView:self]];
        [_delegate sliderDidEndMoving];
    }
    _isUpdating=NO;
 }
```

Comment: where add panGestures to uislider?

Comment: I have added pan gesture to the Knob of slider i.e. an UIView

Comment: ok, when "setData" is called? from viewDidLoad?

Comment: I tried from Both Places